# Cannot find error in sorting time comparison program

Tags: c, time, quicksort, bubble-sort

I've been having some trouble making my code work for comparing the times it takes for quicksort and bubblesort to go through an array. The problem is that the code will compile without errors (according to cygwin) but will give no output to the code, although I have several printf codes there. Could someone help me figure out the issue? Below is my line of code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <time.h>

    void quicksort(int a[ ], int low, int high);
    int split(int a[ ], int low, int high);
    void bubblesort(int a[ ], int low, int high);

    int main(void)
    {
      int i, a[1000]={0}, y= 500, x = -500;
      clock_t start_t, end_t;
      double duration_Q;

      for (i=0; (i <= N); i++){
          my_array[i] = rand() % y + x;
      }

        start_t = clock();

        for(i=500; i<= 5000; i += 500){


            quicksort(a,x,y);   
            bubblesort(a,x,y);
            end_t = clock();

            duration_Q = (end_t -  start_t)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

            printf("***************Report of Performance Comparison***************\n"); 
            printf("                quicksort       bubblesort      (in microseconds)\n"); 
            printf("N=%d", i );printf("%f", duration_Q);printf("%f", duration_Q);printf("array in range [%d,%d]\n", x,y); 
            printf("***************End of Performance Report**********************\n"); 
            printf("\n");
        }

            return(0);
        }

   void quicksort(int a[ ], int low, int high)
   {
      int middle;

      if (low >= high) return;
      middle = split(a, low, high);
      quicksort(a, low, middle - 1);
      quicksort(a, middle + 1, high);
    }

  int split(int a[ ], int low, int high)
   {
     int part_element = a[low];
    for (;;) {
         while (low < high && part_element <= a[high])
    high--;
    if (low >= high) break;
        a[low++] = a[high];
    while (low < high && a[low] <= part_element)
        low++;
    if (low >= high) break;
    a[high--] = a[low];
    }
    a[high] = part_element;
      return high;
   }


  void bubblesort(int a[ ], int low, int high)
  {
     int i, j, temp;
       for (j = high; j > low; j--) {
       for (i = low+1; i <= j;i++) {
          if (a[i] < a[i-1]) {
             temp=a[i];a[i]=a[i-1];a[i-1]=temp;
                                    }
                                }
                    }
  }
```

Comment: Cycwin is not a compiler.

Comment: When I execute your code I get a segfault ..looks there is a bug in your code .. somewhere ..

Comment: I apologize, I meant gcc using Cygwin. Cygwin was the system recommended for use for my windows pc.

Comment: What is the point of testing how long it takes to sort an array that was already sorted? Even if it didn't contain all-0 values. But `split` is indexing `a[100]` by `500`, and `-500` anyway, so segfault is possible/probable.

Comment: That's an ugly formatting.. can you fix it please?

Comment: You have just changed the array to `a[1000]` in the posted code, but you *still* cannot index it by `-500`. Is this the code, or not?

Comment: Sorry, Weather, the purpose of the program is to compare the speed of quicksort and bubble sort when sorting the same array. I also fixed the a[100] to be a[1000], but still have the same issue. Also Eugene, i will do my best to fix, I'm new to the formatting system here.

Comment: My first point was: not only does an array of zeros not need sorting, but if you did start with an array that needs sorting, on the second and other iterations, it, too, is already sorted.

Comment: I dont understand your question Weather. The point was to index the code from a range of [-500 to 500], where those values would be included. This is part of a much larger program that I am working on but I wanted to find the error in this compilation. I thought that the -500 would work as the low value.

Comment: You mean my question "is this the code?" I meant, is this the *actual code* or something that only resembles it? Are you really indexing `a[-500]` or was that just for example? If this is a fantasy on your code, the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: So in terms of is this the code, yes, it is. I will include the part that is missing, which is an array of randomly generated numbers that I wanted to range from an index of [-500,500]. I apologize. I wanted to find the error  in the time functions, as I think the issue lies there.

Comment: But to address your question: you are timing both the sort methods, not comparing each. You read `clock()`, in each iteration, perform both sort methods, then read `clock()` again. You need to time a large number of iterations of each method separately, reading `clock()` *outside* the iteration loop, each sort starting with the same unsorted data..

Comment: on ubuntu linux 14.04, using `gcc`, the posted code does not compile.  If that posted code is what your trying to execute, it is no wonder that nothing is output.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code Suggest 4 spaces per indent level.  indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'. Never use tabs for indenting.  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  1) variable `N` not declared  2) array `myarray[]` not declared.

Comment: regarding this line: `duration_Q = (end_t -  start_t)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`, the calculation will be performed using integer math which means that all fractions will be dropped, Which means the resulting 'double' value will be incorrect.  Suggest: `duration_Q = (end_t -  start_t)*1000.0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` so the multiply and divide will be performed using double math.  (note the change to the constant from `int 1000` to double `1000.0`)

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain. (the 'magic' numbers are: -500, 500, 1000, 5000.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names and using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding this line (and the calls to `quicksort()` and `bubblesort()`, `int x = -500;`  In C, indexes into arrays are always in the range 0...(number of elements into array -1)  A negative index will be treated (depending on the OS and compiler) as either a VERY large number or as referencing memory before the start of the array.